# Link correctly to index.html in Python Django

Tags: python, django, settings, vs-web-site-project

I have a Python Django project with the following files.

proj1/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('website.urls')),
]
```

proj1/website/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return  render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

proj1/website/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

Under proj1/website/templates I have a few .html files.
How do I link to those in my .html files?
I have currently the following written in index.html

```
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

I get error message when I press the link for the index.html though.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/index.html
Using the URLconf defined in leam.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
The current path, index.html, didn't match any of these.
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to specify where the index.html is located with a full path, or what is wrong here? The index.html loads with run manage.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{% url 'website:index' %}">Home</a>
```

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'website'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

Try this, it should work. 
The formula is `{% url '<namespace or app name>:<view name>' %}`

Comment: I get error message:
NoReverseMatch at /
'website' is not a registered namespace

Comment: @muzzex I've edited my answer, check it again pls

Comment: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.